# Digitally signing with the public key

Tags: java

As I understand, a digital signature is obtained by encrypting (the message digest) with your own private key and then the recipient's public key.

In Java, I can't figure out how to use a public key to perform the second stage of signing.

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5WithRSA");
sig.initSign(privateKey);
sig.update(data);
byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();
```

I checked the API, the only methods that use a public key are for verifying...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no recipient involved in a message signature. You can encrypt the signature to the recipient's public key if you want to prevent anyone else from verifying it, but that's not generally considered part of signing the message.

Answer (score 3):

In public key cryptography:

- The private key is used for *signing* and *deciphering/decrypting*.
- The public key is used for *verifying signatures* and *enciphering/encrypting*.

See [the glossary of the TLS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#appendix-B):

> public key cryptography: A class of cryptographic techniques employing two-key ciphers. Messages encrypted with the public key can
> only be decrypted with the associated private key. Conversely,
> messages signed with the private key can be verified with the public
> key.

Although with RSA the mathematical operations used for the signature are very similar to those used for encryption (in that signing more or less the same as "encrypting" the digest), this is not the case for all algorithms (e.g. DSA). In addition, mixing the terminology will cause problems in your overall security reasoning.

What you've done here is the one and only stage of signing. You may want to encrypt the message in addition to this (using the recipient's public key), but that's an independent operation. You may want to look at `Cipher` to do this. Of course, it's not just the signature you've obtained before that you will want to encrypt, but the concatenation of the initial message and its signature. (I'm not sure there would be any point in encrypting the signature only.)

Answer (score 2):

There's no such step as encrypting a digital signature with the recipients public key; it wouldn't be a (generic) digital signature in this case, as only the recipient would be able to decrypt (and thus check) it.

So, yes (without knowing specifics of Java), I'm not surprised the API only offers functions to create one needing your private RSA-key, whereas the recipient needs your public RSA-key to check your signature, which is the second part of the API you mention.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "second stage", encrypting with the private key the hash, or verifying the signature?

The pasted code already give you the signature after calling `update()`. Signature object already does the hash (MD5) and encrypts with the private key (RSA).

To verify the signature you just follow the symmetric steps described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/vstep4.html)